# long string is not matched correctly with XmlReader Java and Jboss on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jboss5.x, string-matching, xmlreader

I encounter a problem when using XmlReader in Java. 
The xml that I have to parse contains sql querys in tags , is a long and I parse xml when I do well on my local JBoss and Windows. One of those querys is quite long, about 3000 characters.

For when the same parsing is done in another Jboss Server deployed on Linux that long query not parse well voge me from certain word to the end, if you take a piece of the query follows from taking the same point.

Given that Jboss has both encoding as UTF-8, the Windows version of Java is 1.6.0_45 and 1.6.0_32 have the linux, and has the xml header

Thank you very much,

Comment: Show us some code. E.g. the ContentHandler implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ContentHandler.characters() call can be fragmented differently depending on the runtime. 
Your SQL Query could be parsed in two blocks, so you need to concatenate the characters sent until the endElement call.

Comment: Still, please post the ContentHandler implementation (maybe the fixed version), so other people may learn something.